# How to search from comma separated string in comma separated column mysql

Tags: mysql

I am working on a project where I have to code for job filters.
In this when I filters for salaries it sends salary id's in array like:

```
job_salary = array(
              [0]=>3,
              [1]=>4,
              [2]=>5,
              [3]=>6,
              [4]=>7,
              [5]=>8  
              )
```

and job in my jobs table contains multiple salaries using comma string.

```
id  salary_ids 
 1    2,4,6
 2    1,3,5
 3    4,5
 4    9,1
```

So if i search for value 3, and 5 in array form like

```
job_salary = array(
              [0]=>3,
              [1]=>5
              );
```

It should return me the second and third row because these rows contain value 3 and 5.

Comment: Welcome to relational database world. Please normalize your schema, it would be much easier than parsing csv columns.

Comment: It means i can't achieve without normalizing multiple salaries in new table ?

Comment: Yes. Either fix your schema, or don’t bother using an RDBMS; it’s a straightforward choice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use it like below let me know if it works

```
$values=array("1","2","3");

foreach($values as $val)
{
    $query="Select * from table_name where  FIND_IN_SET('".$val."',column_name)";
$result=mysql_query($query);
$data=mysql_fetch_array($result);
$dbval[]=$data['column_name'];

}

print_r($dbval);
```

Comment: I know that it's not a good way to accomplish this task, but because at this moment where i can't make manipulations in my database, i have to go with your answer, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please try  again like  this

1. For Postgres & MySQL:

   ```
   SELECT FIND_IN_SET(5, userid) AS result 
   FROM department
   ```
2. For PostgreSQL:

   ```
   SELECT * 
   FROM TABLENAME f
   WHERE 'searchvalue' = ANY (string_to_array(COLUMNNAME,','))
   ```

Example

```
select * 
from customer f
where '11' = ANY (string_to_array(customerids,','))
```